# Running Azure Active Directory Module via a batch file

Tags: powershell, azure

I am creating a script in a batch file which is supposed to tell Azure to run instead of powershell. Does anybody know how to call upon Azure? I believe the way to call powershell is powershell.exe but cannot figure out azure. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think Azure has an installed executable?

Comment: I dont know for sure, this is the first time I am working with Azure so trying to see if there is a way to run it via cmd

Comment: Azure has a set of PowerShell cmdlets for remote administration and reporting. Whilst you could call those from a batch file, there wouldn't be any point.

Comment: The thing is the report I am trying to run will not run with powershell, it has to be azure. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @AliG, there is no such thing as Azure on the client. Azure is Microsoft's cloud service. Everything on Azure runs in the cloud. The PowerShell library that they provide allows you to control Azure from the client instead of having to do everything via the web site. Which report are you trying to run?

Comment: I was trying to run a report on o365 accounts. I can get it if i run Azure as admin and input the commands. But I was hoping that I could create a .ps1 file which would have the report running from azure because the report will not be generated if i use straight powershell

Answer (score 0):

[How to install and configure Azure PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)

This article shows you how to set up PowerShell to be able to control Azure remotely. You have to access the Azure PowerShell cmdlets and authenticate to your Azure tenant.

The [Script Centre](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/scripts/) has many examples of Azure PowerShell scripts that might give you further information and help.